# Rails 3: unit test works with ruby but not rake

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, rake

I have the following class in a Rails 3 app:

```
class AssetAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.ANNOTATION
    self.find_by_table_name('annotations')
  end
  ...
end
```

In another class, I refer to this method in a `validates` call:

```
validates :attribute_type_id, :attr_correct => {attr: AssetAttribute.ANNOTATION}
```

When I run my tests with a Ruby command line, everything works:

```
ruby -Itest test/unit/annotation_test.rb
```

But when I try it with Rake:

```
rake test:units
```

I suddenly get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'xxx' for nil:NilClass` where "xxx" is any method on `AssetAttribute`.

Why are these tests running differently? I'm running Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3

**Edit:** Fixed `AssetAttribute` declaration

Comment: Where is this class in your folder structure?

Comment: Not sure which class you mean, so here's a bunch of'em: `app/models/asset_attribute.rb`, `app/models/annotation.rb`, `test/unit/annotation_test.rb`, `app/validators/correct_attribute_type_validator.rb`.

Comment: AssetAttribute, the one that is nil EDIT: Oh, ok, ty

Comment: Ah. Well, `app/models`

Comment: So it is `class AssetAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base`, correct?

Comment: Correct. I've updated the question.